# Trouble reading in geojson/json file into R for plotting on map

Tags: json, r, leaflet, geojson, ggmap

I'm trying to read in a json file which contains polylines into R for plotting in leaflet or ggmap. The file is in the geojson format.

The file can be found at: http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v4/gis/statistischesector.json

I've tried:

```
library(rgdal) 
library(jsonlite)
library(leaflet)

geojson <- readLines("statistischesector.json", warn = FALSE) %>%
  paste(collapse = "\n") %>%
  fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE)
```

This actually reads in the file but it seems to be in a wrong format for further processing.

Alternatively:

```
readOGR(dsn="~/statistischesector.json", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
```

Returns:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open data source
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Can you prove that the path is correct?

Comment: I shortened the path in the example for readability. 
When I do:

path<-"C://users//jbo//Dropbox//R_scripts//GO//statistischesector.json"

file.exists(path)
#this returns TRUE

readOGR(dsn = path, layer = "OGRGeoJSON")
#this returns the error described above

Comment: My guess is I have to do some kind of transformation on the file after I read it with the readLines function..

Comment: I figured it was wrong since I couldn't plot the polylines with leaflet.


leaflet() %>% setView(lng = 4.401, lat = 51.21, zoom = 10) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addGeoJSON(geojson)

Comment: You mean you get the world map but nothing extra?

Comment: Yes indeed. In the meantime I've managed to save the JSON file which I read in with readLines as a geojson file by subselecting some data and then using "toGeoJSON". However, I'm also not able to read in this new file with the readOGR function (same error).

Comment: I tried the same (extracting the geometry information from geojson$data) which - I guess - is the same you obtained by using toGeoJSON. Could you [validate that you actually get geoJSON](http://geojsonlint.com/)?

Comment: According to this site (which is really cool btw) it's an invalid geojson. I did indeed try to subselect the polygon information out of geojson$data.
Thank you for the effort! 
This is the error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pq8kiq1rdy0xfpt/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Can you make a link to the converted data? From your screen dump it looks as if the strings are not encoded in quotes.

Comment: The formatting looks wrong indeed. When there is supposed to be coordinates for a type "point" new information starts on a type polygon

Comment: Okay I've now tried a bunch of different things and I'm pretty sure that it's the `addGeoJSON` function that's is pretty specific about the input it wants. If I feed it something that is validates geoJSON then it still doesn't print anything (although I must say I've become quite familiar with the area around Antwerpen by now). If you want to pursue this then it might be better for us to take it off SO until we've found a solution?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time ekstroem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way

```
library("jsonlite")
library("leaflet")
x <- jsonlite::fromJSON("http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v4/gis/statistischesector.json", FALSE)

geoms <- lapply(x$data, function(z) {
  dat <- tryCatch(jsonlite::fromJSON(z$geometry, FALSE), error = function(e) e)
  if (!inherits(dat, "error")) {
    list(type = "FeatureCollection",
         features = list(
           list(type = "Feature", properties = list(), geometry = dat)
         ))
  }
})

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addGeoJSON(geojson = geoms[1]) %>%
  setView(
    lng = mean(vapply(geoms[1][[1]]$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]], "[[", 1, 1)),
    lat = mean(vapply(geoms[1][[1]]$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]], "[[", 1, 2)),
    zoom = 12)
```

[image]

`leaflet::addGeoJSON` does indeed want a particular format. E.g., the geojson strings are fine on http://geojsonlint.com/ but they need to be tweaked to work with `leaflet`. also, there was at least one string that was malformed, so i added a `tryCatch` to skip those

**all polygons**

```
gg <- list(type = "FeatureCollection", 
           features = 
             Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(x$data, function(z) {
               dat <- tryCatch(jsonlite::fromJSON(z$geometry, FALSE), error = function(e) e)
               if (!inherits(dat, "error")) {
                 list(type = "Feature", 
                      properties = list(), 
                      geometry = dat)
               } else {
                 NULL
               }
             }))
)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addGeoJSON(geojson = gg) %>% 
  setView(lng = 4.5, lat = 51.3, zoom = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sckott! Is it possible to plot all polylines at once? I've noticed you can plot different ones in your current code by increasing the index right after 'geoms'.