# Trouble reading geojson data into R

Tags: r, geojson

I am trying to read in geojson data to use with the `leaflet` package.  I have tried reading in the data multiple ways, but I cannot get it to plot. Data is [here](https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/772f3621fa354ec9abf3ba33f3ace59e_0.geojson).

- I tried using the code in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391869/trouble-reading-in-geojson-json-file-into-r-for-plotting-on-map).  The first block gave me a blank map.  The second gave me a map with no new lines added.
- I also tried the code from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/json.html). I am new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(leaflet)
library(jsonlite)
download.file("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/772f3621fa354ec9abf3ba33f3ace59e_0.geojson", "RPD_Sections.geojson")
x = fromJSON("RPD_Sections.geojson", FALSE)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoJSON(x) %>% setView(
    lng = mean(vapply(x$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]], "[[", 1, 1)),
    lat = mean(vapply(x$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]], "[[", 1, 2)),
    zoom = 12)
```

[image]

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much! I have a couple of different geojson files, and this works for them all!

Answer (score 0):

A bit more concise, but gives the same result

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
sf <- sf::st_read("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/772f3621fa354ec9abf3ba33f3ace59e_0.geojson")

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = sf)
```

This also makes the assumption your GeoJSON only consists of polygons